# Active Directory COM Exception - An operations error occurred (0x80072020)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, com, active-directory

I am getting an intermittent COM Exception "**An operations error occurred (0x80072020)**" (shown below) when I try and query Active Directory using the method **[GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344648.aspx)**

Here is my code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "Group to find");
```

I am receiving Exception:

```
Inner Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
  at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
  at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
  at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
```

The code is running from a **Windows service** on a **Windows 2003 SP2 server**.

I have found another Stack Overflow question, [Active Directory, enumerating user's groups, COM exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741479/active-directory-enumerating-users-gropus-com-exception/5798403#5798403), suggesting that **enabling Kerberos** as an option in the PrincipalContext constructor will fix this problem but I am receiving a *different hex code* than in this question.

**My questions are**:

1. Is this particular COM Exception definitely an authentication issue?  I need to be sure that this will 100% fix the problem before releasing the software.
2. Is there a resource somewhere which lists all the possible COM exception hex codes so that I can help myself a bit better in the future?

Comment: It is not a COM error.  The underlying error is LDAP_OPERATIONS_ERROR.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746386%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: +1 for the request for a reference listing exceptions and error codes that might arise when working with Active Directory.  I'm also looking for such a reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've now found another answer [Unable to add user with CrmService API in Dynamics CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504487/unable-to-add-user-with-crmservice-api-in-dynamics-crm) which states that 0x80072020 is indeed a permission issue.  I have changed my service to run under a domain level account instead of the local system account and this seems to have cured my problem.

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a while in case anyone else has any observations about this particular error or the Exception occurs again.

Answer (score 44):

The issue is often that the context for which the Active Directory calls is made is under a user that does not have permissions (also can happen when `identity impersonate="true"` in ASP.NET, due to the fact that the users token is a "secondary token" that cannot be used when authenticating against another server from: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f188029c-51cf-4b50-966a-eee7160d0353/an-operations-error-occured).

The following code will ensure that the block of code your are running, is run under the context of say the `AppPool` (i.e. `NETWORKSERVICE`) that your service or site is running under.

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
   var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomain.com");
   var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.Name, "PowerUsers");
   if (groupPrincipal != null)
   {
      //code to get the infomation
   }

}
```

However, one super important detail is that *all the code calling Active Directory* must be in that block. I had used some code a team member of mine wrote that was returning a `LINQ` query results of type `Users` (custom class), but not evaluting the expression (bad practice). Therefore the expression tree was returned instead of the results.

What ended up happening is the calling code eventually evaluated the results and the `An operations error occurred` message still appeared. I though the code fix above didn't work. When in fact it did, but there was code evaluating the results outside the block.

In a nutshell, make sure **all** code to access Active Directory is inside that `using` block and the exception should be fixed one the service/app is deployed to the server.

Answer (score 9):

Granted this is 2 years later, I ran into this and found that the following solved my issue:

```
using System.Web.Hosting;
...
...
// Code here runs as the logged on user

using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) {
// This code runs as the application pool user
     DirectorySearcher searcher ...
}
```

[reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appvbeta/thread/f188029c-51cf-4b50-966a-eee7160d0353/)

#### 3rd party

The [HostingEnvironment.Impersonate Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) was available in .Net 4.8. But  starting with .NET Core 1.0 it is no longer available

> The requested page is not available for .NET Core 1.0. You have been
> redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

Comment: Does this work outside of asp.net?  I need this code for integration in server side wcf

Comment: Worked on MVC4. How are you running this on the server side?

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me in ASP.NET (Windows 2008 R2 / IIS7) where I was messing around with Web.config and this error started happening on every FindByIdentity call.  The root cause was that the App Pool was running as DefaultAppPool, and it started working again once I changed it to run as Network Service.  I don't quite understand why it would get changed, but it did.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I got success after changing the application pool as below:
   Process model
      load user profile = true

Comment: Thanks.  This makes sense.  I start seeing similar errors with some new app pool created wtihout setting load profile

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the web app pool was running as "DefaultAppPool" which did not have sufficient access to connect to Company's Active Directory. So, I impersonated an account which has access to AD in my code and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a error code, **"An operations error occurred (0x80072020)"**, it might mean **"Access denied"**.

- Check your Web server whether or not in AD Domain

  - If not you have to put authentication into PrincipalContext.

Example (Something like this):

```c#
public bool foo(String username, String password) {
    string ADIPaddress = "[ipaddress]";
    ContextOptions options = ContextOptions.Negotiate;
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, AD_IPaddress, null, options, username, password);
    bool isAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password, options);
    return isAuthenticated;
}
```

Reference

- [C#網頁登入AD網域進行LDAP驗證](http://adamschen9921.pixnet.net/blog/post/96401557-c%23%E7%B6%B2%E9%A0%81%E7%99%BB%E5%85%A5ad%E7%B6%B2%E5%9F%9F%E9%80%B2%E8%A1%8Cldap%E9%A9%97%E8%AD%89)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I ran into the same problem with trying to login to one of the domain controllers, I have 2 domain controllers, 1 of them is working and the other is not working, I believe it has something to do with the user profile, still investigating...