# Can't create PrincipalContext in ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices, principalcontext

I am using this code from a .NET Forms application to try and create a PrincipalContext object.

```
var oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(
                ContextType.Domain, 
                "mydomain.workgroup",
                "CN=users,CN=mydomain,CN=workgroup", 
                ContextOptions.Bind,                    
                "ADAdmin", 
                "ADAdminPassword");
```

I also tried this with but got the same error.

```
var oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(
                ContextType.Domain, 
                "mydomain.workgroup",
                "CN=users,CN=mydomain,CN=workgroup", 
                ContextOptions.Negotiate,                    
                "ADAdmin", 
                "ADAdminPassword");
```

I have also tried `ADAdmin@mydomain.workgroup` as the user id.

I am getting this error

```
Message=An operations error occurred.

StackTrace=   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_ConnectedServer()
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

InnerException=An operations error occurred.

StackTrace=   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_SchemaEntry()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsContainer(DirectoryEntry de)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx..ctor(DirectoryEntry ctxBase, Boolean ownCtxBase, String username, String password, ContextOptions options)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.CreateContextFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
```

I am logged in as a user with DomainAdmin privileges in AD.

The computer I am running this from has DomainAdmin privileges in AD.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529386/error-an-operations-error-occurred-in-system-directoryservices-accountmanagem) link has a solution but it is for `IIS` and it didn't work for me.

[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1970631.aspx?Error%20An%20operations%20error%20occurred%20when%20using%20FindByIdentity) solution didn't work either.

Comment: Try `PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com", "CN=users,CN=mydomain,CN=workgroup", ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate, userName, password);` Since you already have admin privileges, just try to bind simply by providing the name of the domain. `PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com");`

Comment: I used `SecureSocketLayer` and got this error `The ContextOptions passed are invalid for this store type.  Either Negotiate or SimpleBind must be specified and they cannot be combined.`

Comment: It looks like you don't have `SSL` installed. Try `SimpleBind`.

Comment: @Burzum the second suggestion in your first comment worked, I just used the domain and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Burzum I'm having the same problem with an ASP.NET application running on the same server in IIS7.5.  I changed the AppPool identity to run as the domainadmin user but it doesn't help.  I'm using the same code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please open a new question and provide some details on your IIS.

Comment: @Burzum I made the same change to my ASP.NET application and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that the user has already admin privileges, you only need to specify `ContextType` and your `Domain`.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com");
```