# Active Directory Domain error on server machine

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, active-directory-group

I developed web application with asp.net. I'm using active directory domain for user info. It's well run on localhost. But I have deployed on server machine. It's not running.

Plase help me.

Sorry for my bad English .

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or logs?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

An operations error occurred.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.


Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Stack Trace: 


[DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +627365
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) +98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the code you are using, but there are couple of questions on Stack Overflow that had a similar error and were resolved. The links to the questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529386/error-an-operations-error-occurred-in-system-directoryservices-accountmanagem) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285503/active-directory-com-exception-an-operations-error-occured-0x80072020/19036826#19036826).

Basically these links talk about the permission issue when the code is executed. It is possible that the impersonation is set in web.config as the first post suggests.